# Regular expression to split the data frame string into columns in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to regular expression. I have to split a dataframe row into 3 columns based on the pattern using regular expression.

Example row in data frame:

```
"Sample String(just a / string) 04/04/2014 to ongoing"
```

I am trying below regular expression but not working:

```
pat = re.compile("(?P<String_Name>[a-zA-Z- )(/ ]*)(?P<START_DATE>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})(?P<stop_date>[a-zA-Z]*)?")
df=new_df.text.str.extract(pat)
```

Need output like this:

```
String_Name = Sample String(just a / string)
Start_Date = 04/04/2014
Stop_Date = ongoing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(?P<String_Name>.*?)\s*(?P<START_DATE>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})\sto\s+(?P<stop_date>.*)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CNhdQp/1). Regulex graph:

[image]

Pandas test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['Sample String(just a / string) 04/04/2014 to ongoing']})
rx = r'(?P<String_Name>.*?)\s*(?P<START_DATE>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})\sto\s+(?P<stop_date>.*)'
df1 = df['text'].str.extract(rx)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
                      String_Name  START_DATE stop_date
0  Sample String(just a / string)  04/04/2014   ongoing
```